# Different link colours in user's list of answers

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, design

Some links to answers on my user page are the regular colour, and some are blue.  What's the difference between the two?

[image: screenshot]

**Update**

It appears that the behaviour works with Safari, but not with Firefox 7.0.1 (Mac OS 10.6.8). That is, the links are coloured but they don't seem to change as you visit them.)

Answer (score 12):

The blue links point to answers you recently visited, the others are red.

Click one of the other links and go back to the list of answers, that link should then have changed the color to blue.

The color the browsing users sees depend on visits by him, not on visits by the profile owner. Just in the case your view your own profile it's the same.

Comment: A quick test doesn't actually show the expected behaviour. If I click on one of the orange links and then go back to the list of questions and reload the page, the link doesn't change to blue. Maybe there's a threshold of visits? (That's what prompted the question originally; the list of questions that were blue didn't seem to correlate with any of my activity.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Perhaps test with a different browser or on a different computer.

Comment: You're right, it works as expected in Safari.  I've updated the question and added a [tag:bug] tag.

Comment: Did you try to reload the page after you went back? Maybe it is showing you the previously rendered page to save rendering time?

Comment: @matth Yes (that's what my first comment said.) Paulo seems to have found a relevant link on the issue here: [How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7290959)

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was already tired, not reading your comment carefully...

Comment: is this still happening? I can't repro

Answer (score 9):

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I thought of posting this text as a comment, but it would be too big.</sub>

Stefan is right, the blue color means you visited that link. `:)`

**Just to add some technical/sorcery stuff:**

I checked the main site stylesheet (`css`) and found the following entries:

```
a:visited {
   color:#3989bb;
}

a {
   ...
   color:#e3c485;
   ...
}
```

The `a` tag refers to a hyperlink, that is, a word, group of words, or image that you can click on to jump to a new document or a new section within the current document.<sup>1</sup>

The word right after the `a` tag and the `:` symbol means a pseudo-class, that is, a reference to add special effects to the tag<sup>2</sup>. In our example, `a:visited` means that a visited hyperlink will be set according to the key/value entries in the group.

The colors are defined using a hexadecimal notation for the combination of red, green, and blue color values (RGB)<sup>3</sup>. We can check what colors those numbers represent:

`#e3c485`

[image: Color 1]

`#3989bb`

[image: Color 2]

I hope I picked up the right colors, the `css` file is huge. But the idea is the same. `:)`

**References**

1. [HTML Hyperlinks](http://w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)
2. [Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)
3. [HTML Colors](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Everything looks fine to me, using FF 22.0 on OSX.  I marking this is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), not because it didn't happen, but because there's nothing to de bug anymore.